# Evaluate $\int_{\pi/6}^\frac{\pi}{2}\csc\left(t\right)\cot\left(t\right)dt $

Tags: calculus

So I consider the integral:
$$\int_{\pi/6}^\frac{\pi}{2}\csc\left(t\right)\cot\left(t\right)\space \text{dt}$$

In my notes I have: $$=-\csc\left(t\right)+C$$
Then I take the limit of $\csc(t)$:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{6}}-\csc(t)=-2$$
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}-\csc(t)=-1$$

Then I subtract $F(b)-F(a)$,

$-1-(-2)=1$ but I don't know how I arrived at $-\csc(t)+C$

Comment: You cannot split them. They are not equal at all.

Comment: I think you are confusing the definite and indefinite integrals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot split up your integral like you have tried in your original post. In order to evaluate this, notice that $$\frac{d}{dx} (-\csc x) = \csc x \cot x$$
Therefore, $\int\csc x \cot x = -\csc x + C$. Then you use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, as you have noted.

Answer (score 0):

If you write it terms of sine and cosine, you'll get $$\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x}$$ which you can do u-sub on ($u=\sin x$), neatly cancelling the cosine in the numerator.

P.S. in general, you can't split products inside integrals. That only works for addition or subtraction, or multiplication by a constant.